# Or conditions in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two queries,

`Post.where(:group_id.in => group_ids, :deleted => false)
Post.where(:user_id=>user.id,:deleted=>false)`

I need to combine these query using or condition.
I tried like,

`Post.where(:deleted => false).or({:user_id=>user.id},{:group_id.in => group_ids})`
and
`Post.any_of({:group_id.in=>group_ids},{:user_id=>user.id})`
but I didn't get results.

Comment: So basically you want to merge the results of these two queries?

Answer (score 23):

You can do it like that:

```
Post.any_of({:group_id.in => group_ids, :deleted => false}, {:user_id => user.id, :deleted => false})
```

or:

```
Post.all_of(:deleted => true, :or => [{:group_id.in => group_ids}, {:user_id => user.id}])
```

You can call `selector` on any of these expressions to see mongodb query that will be generated to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks. I was working on mongo 1.2.1, It is working when I upgrade it to 1.8.1.